# Membership Plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation, membership, plugin-members, members

I'm looking for a good plugin for premium blog content. My client wants to offer 30 trial that's free as well as a paid monthly/6 months/yearly plan.

It should display an except of the post for everyone even when they're on the site as a guest without any membership, trial or premium.

It also needs to receive payments through PayPal and automatically turn on the subscription after payment.

I want to be able to customize the register page to add additional fields like address and phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's plenty out there, http://winkpress.com/membership-plugin/ has a good write up on most of them and stays pretty unbiased.

I can't tell you a good one but if you come across Magic Members stay well clear of it. It's buggy as hell and their support staff only help if its an easy fix. When you point out something that actually doesn't work they simply ignore your request for support.

Answer (score 0):

http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership

Good group of developers and nice support.

Answer (score 0):

The most powerful membership plugin I've found is Digital Access Pass (DAP). It allows for powerful 'dripping' of content on your schedule to your members. This is very attractive if you want to automate your content delivery.

Check it out at:
http://www.digitalaccesspass.com/

Just a happy customer.

Answer (score 0):

Give Paid Memberships Pro a shot, which is 100% open source and available for free in the WordPress repository:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/

It supports the features you need. To add additional fields to the checkout, you need to do a bit of programming right now. Here is an example of that:
https://gist.github.com/1389944

You can purchase support and other services for PMPro at:
http://www.paidmembershipspro.com

Good luck.